# How to change value of variable passed as argument?

Tags: c, parameter-passing

How to change value of variable passed as argument in C?
I tried this:

```
void foo(char *foo, int baa){
    if(baa) {
        foo = "ab";
    } else {
        foo = "cb";
    }
}
```

and call:

```
char *x = "baa";
foo(x, 1);
printf("%s\n", x);
```

but it prints `baa` why?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If(baa)?  Its not a bool value, is this legal in c?

Comment: @Induster There are no Boolean types in C. All Boolean logic is done with ints.

Comment: @Phonon, wrong. Since C99 the language has `_Bool` as a primitive type and `bool` in "stdbool.h".

Comment: All the same, boolean comparisons in C still simply check against zero-equivalence; while there are a number of implementations of _Bool it's typically just an integer word with restricted zero-or-one value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're wanting to change where a `char*` points, therefore you're going to need to accept an argument in `foo()` with *one more level of indirection*; a `char**` (pointer to a `char` pointer).

Therefore `foo()` would be rewritten as:

```
void foo(char **foo /* changed */, int baa)
{
   if(baa) 
   {
      *foo = "ab"; /* changed */
   }
   else 
   {
      *foo = "cb"; /* changed */
   }
}
```

Now when calling `foo()`, you'll pass a *pointer to `x`* using the address-of operator (`&`):

```
foo(&x, 1);
```

The reason why your incorrect snippet prints `baa` is because you're simply assigning a new value to the *local* variable `char *foo`, which is unrelated to `x`. Therefore the value of `x` is never modified.

Comment: @Jesse: No I'm not. This simply points `x` to a different string literal.

Comment: You`re right, will withdraw my comment (ideone.com was giving a runtime error which led to my confusion).

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple issues:

```
void foo(char *foo, int baa)
{
    if (baa) 
        foo = "ab";
    else 
        foo = "cb";
}
```

This code changes the local pointer, but does nothing with it.  To copy strings around, you need to use `strcpy()` to keep the interface the same:

```
void foo(char *foo, int baa)
{
    if (baa) 
        strcpy(foo, "ab");
    else 
        strcpy(foo, "cb");
}
```

However, before doing that, you'd need to ensure that `foo` in the function points at modifiable memory.  The calling code needs to be modified to ensure that:

```
char x[] = "baa";
foo(x, 1);
printf("%s\n", x);
```

Alternatively, you can keep `x` as a pointer and revise the function interface:

```
void foo(char **foo, int baa)
{
    if (baa) 
        *foo = "ab";
    else 
        *foo = "cb";
}
```

and the calling sequence:

```
char *x = "baa";
foo(&x, 1);
printf("%s\n", x);
```

Both mechanisms work, but do so in their different ways.  There are different sets of issues with each.  There isn't a single 'this is better than that' decision; which is better depends on circumstances outside the scope of the code fragments shown.

Answer (score 7):

You question is titled in a generic way. You've already got answers for your specific problem. I'm going to add couple of illustrative examples for `int` and `double` types.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incrementInt(int* in, int inc)
{
   *in += inc;
}

void incrementDouble(double* in, double inc)
{
   *in += inc;
}

int main()
{
   int i = 10;
   double d = 10.2;

   printf("i: %d, d: %lf\n", i, d);

   incrementInt(&i, 20);
   incrementDouble(&d, 9.7);

   printf("i: %d, d: %lf\n", i, d);
}
```

Output:

```
i: 10, d: 10.200000
i: 30, d: 19.900000
```

Answer (score 0):

in function foo, you are changing argument foo only locally. when function foo ends, argument x is still x. You didn't change it in foo. you only copied it and called foo.

also, look at @Greg Hewgill comment.