# Set structure pointer to NULL in function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I try to free structure pointer using function and then check for NULL. It doesn't work!

```
typedef struct{
    int * num;
} D;

void freeD(D * a){
    free(a->num);
    free(a);
    a=NULL;
}
int main(){
    D * smth = malloc(sizeof(D));
    smth->num = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    freeD(smth);
    if(smth==NULL){
    printf("It's NULL");
    }
}
```

Comment: You change the local copy of the pointer, passed as the parameter `a`.

Comment: Beginner error `D *a` is a local variable of `freeD()` change his value inside the function don't change the value of `smth` in the main.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459691/how-to-change-value-of-variable-passed-as-argument

Comment: a=NULL; has no effect

Comment: comparable with  `void foo(int n) { n = 1; }` pretty useless huh?

Comment: @alinsoar `a=NULL;` has no effect is true yet is an oft used coding style to improve chances of error should `a` get inadvertently get use later without a new assignment.  So, not a bad thing to do in general, yet a bit odd at the end of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the pointer by reference that is by using pointer to the pointer.

For example

```
void freeD(D ** a){
    free( ( *a )->num);
    free(*a);
    *a=NULL;
}

//...

freeD( &smth );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have passed the parameter by value instead of passing the parameter by reference.

**What have you done**
Let us assume smth=0x0030; 
*where address(smth) = 0x0100 && value(smth) = 0x0030*.
So when you do freeD(smth), you are actually passing ***value(smth)*** which is 0x0030. Meanwhile, in the function freeD():- 
*address(a) = 0x0200 && value(a) = 0x0030*
So when you do set

> a = NULL

you are actually setting the value(a) = NULL where address(a)=0x0200; instead of doing it at the address=0x0100;

**What you should have done**

```
void freeD(D ** a){
free((*a)->num);
free(*a);
*a=NULL; 
}

int main(){
//...    
freeD(&smth);
//...
}
```

Comment: "Dude"... `x0030` do you mean `0x0030`? you forget to format your code.

Comment: yeah... the same, it was just an example. But thanks for reminding how to write hexCode :)