# How to change the value of a variable passed as an argument and also use the value for an array

Tags: c, function, pointers

This is my example code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void Func(int a[], int b) {
    a[b] = 1;
    b += 5;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[10];
    int b = 0;
    printf("%d\n", b);
    Func(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", a[0]);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

And I want the program to print:

```
0
1
5
```

I've tried changing the function by making `b` a pointer:

```c
void Func(int a[], int *b)
```

... and by writing `*b += 5`. Also, I've changed the call of the function to:

```c
int a[10];
int *b = 0;
// ...
Func(a, &b);
```

Is it possible to manipulate `b` and to use it?

---

*Note: I've tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459691/how-to-change-value-of-variable-passed-as-argument)*

Comment: @DilDeath, Try `void Func(int a[], int *b) { a[*b] = 1; *b += 5; }` and call it with `Func(a,&b);`.  Is that change acceptable?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well it works but in my real program it does some anything except what i've expected to so i'll check on it thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```c
> void Func(int a[], int b){
>    a[b] = 1; // OK
>    b += 5;   // useless
> }
> ```

The problem with this code is that `Func` is assigning a local copy of `b`, and this has no effect outside of the function.

To get the expected output:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void Func(int a[], int *b) {
   a[*b] = 1;
   *b += 5;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[10];
    int b = 0;

    printf("%d\n", b);    // print value of b
    Func(a, &b);          // pass address of b to Func
    printf("%d\n", a[0]);
    printf("%d\n", b);    // print value of b again
}
```

`Func` still has a local copy named `b`, but this copy is a pointer which may point to the `b` object in `main`. This allows us to modify the pointed-to object with `*b += 5`.

Answer (score 1):

For that you want to use `a` and `b` as a pointer, because `a` is an array and `b` you want to modify the value inside the function.

But you can't send directly `b` inside the function is why you to send as `&b` to give the address where the variable is stored in that way you don't copy the value of `b` but directly change it.

```c
void foo(int *a, int *b) {
    a[*b] = 1;
    *b += 5;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[10] = {0};
    int b = 0;

    printf("b = [%i]\n", b);
    foo(a, &b);
    printf("a[0] = [%i]\n", a[b]);
    printf("b = [%i]\n", b);
}
```

Comment: you write int *a in parameters since int *a = int a[] right ?

Comment: @DilDeath In a parameter list `int a[]`  is strictly the same as ` int *a`