# Deleting characters more than once in a word in a string

Tags: c, duplicates, char, c-strings

I'm a very new programmer and I'm having difficulties with a string problem in C. I want to output the 'words' with no letter duplication. It's okay to duplicate in other words. For example, if I type 'hello everyone' I want to output it as 'helo evryon'. Also, I can assume that the input string will consist of only lower case letters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isduplicate(char ch, char str[]);

void eliminate(char res[], char token[], int j, int tok)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tok; i++)
    {
        if (!isduplicate(token[i], res))
        {
            res[j] = token[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

bool isduplicate(char ch, char str[])
{
    int *res = strchr(str, ch);
    if (res != NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool notalphabet(char ch)
{
    if (ch < 65 || (ch > 90 && ch < 97) || ch > 122)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    static int j = 0;
    char str[100], res[100];
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(str);
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        char token[100];
        int tok = 0;
        while (notalphabet(str[i]))
        {
            token[tok] = str[i];
            i++;
            tok++;
        }
        eliminate(res, token, j, tok);
        i++;
        res[j] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    res[j] = '\0';
    printf("The resulting string is:");
    puts(res);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code. But there is no output.

Comment: `gets(str);` - You must read [*Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965)

Comment: Avoid constructs like `if(ch<65 || (ch>90 && ch<97) || ch>122)` - use the functions found in [`<ctype.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) to determine character classes.

Comment: You can use a status array (indexed by unsigned character) to tell you whether a letter has been used.

Comment: (Even without using `ctype.h`, comparing via chars like `ch < 'a' || ch > 'z'` is more readable).

Comment: @Rogue That relies on ASCII encoding, common as it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change value of variable passed as argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459691/how-to-change-value-of-variable-passed-as-argument)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `eliminate(res,token,j,tok);`, the function receives a *copy* of the value held by the variable `j`. Incrementing this value inside the function does not affect the value held by the variable in `main`.

As such, `res[j]='\0';` is always `res[0]='\0';`, creating an empty string.

`res` is not null-terminated when it is passed to `strchr` the first time.

---

Instead of all the copying, simply try printing a character only when it is the first occurrence found by `strchr`.

Use `fgets` to read a line, and `strtok` to split the string on spaces (and the newline read by `fgets`, in this case).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_no_duplicates(const char *msg)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; msg[i]; i++) {
        if (msg + i == strchr(msg, msg[i]))
            putchar(msg[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[256];

    printf("Enter a line of text: ");

    if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        perror("fgets");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *tok = strtok(line, " \n");

    while (tok) {
        print_no_duplicates(tok);
        putchar(' ');
        tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

```
Enter a line of text: hello everyone
helo evryon
```

If one can assume the input consists only of lowercase characters, then there is no particular need to double-check this. If you still want to, [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower) is the function to use.

---

Alternatively, create a lookup table to filter values already seen.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void print_no_duplicates(const char *msg)
{
    bool seen[UCHAR_MAX] = { 0 };

    for (size_t i = 0; msg[i]; i++) {
        unsigned char ch = msg[i];

        if (!seen[ch]) {
            putchar(msg[i]);
            seen[ch] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I tried yours and it worked. Then I try to understand the code. But there are many things I don't know since I'm just  like a beginner level.I totally cant understand yours.

Comment: Which parts do you find confusing? I can try to clarify them with annotations and/or links to documentation.

Comment: How to tell... I'm a low level programmer and your codes are too high for me. I haven't learned that kind of advance things such as(stdlib, size_t,perror,etc.).So... It's somehow complicate for me.

Comment: None of these are particularly advanced, and you will be learning them soon enough: `<stdlib.h`> gives us `EXIT_FAILURE`, a value to be used as an exit status from the program (the return value from `main`) when
 we want to indicate the program has failed to do what it wanted to do - it is the opposite of `EXIT_SUCCESS`. [Read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status).

Comment: `size_t` is really just a very large *unsigned* integer, one that can hold any memory offset possible in your system. Because something like `int` may not always be large enough to do this, it's a good habit to use `size_t` when accessing array indices. [Read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t). `perror` prints an error message about the last thing that went wrong with a library function. [Read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror)

Comment: Thanks you.I'll study more about them and try to understand it again.<3

Answer (score 0):

Using magic numbers like these

```
if(ch<65 || (ch>90 && ch<97) || ch>122)
```

makes your program unreadable. Instead use a standard function as `isalpha` or `islower` declared in header `<ctype.h>`.

Declaring the variable `j` with the storage class specifier `static`

```
static int j = 0;
```

does not make sense.

The function `gets`  is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead you can write for example

```
scanf( "%99[^\n]", str );
```

This while loop

```
while(notalphabet(str[i]))
{
    token[tok]=str[i];
    i++;
    tok++;
}
```

stores in the array `token`  symbols that are not letters. Also you need to check whether a terminating zero character is encountered. So you should write at least like

```
while( str[i] && !notalphabet(str[i] ) )
```

The variable `j` is passed to the function `eliminate` by value.

```
eliminate(res,token,j,tok);
```

It means that it stays unchanged.

The array `res` does not contain a string when it is passed to the function `isduplicate`. So using it in the call of `strchr`

```
int *res=strchr(str,ch);
```

results in undefined behavior.

I would write a separate function the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *eliminate_duplicates( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;

    while ( *s2 !=  '\0' )
    {
        while (*s2 != '\0' && !isalpha( ( unsigned char )( *s2 ) ))
        {
            *p++ = *s2++;
        }

        for (const char *start_pos = p; isalpha( ( unsigned char )*s2 ); ++s2 )
        {
            const char *current_pos = start_pos;

            while (current_pos != p && *current_pos != *s2) ++current_pos;

            if (current_pos == p) *p++ = *s2;
        }
    }

    *p = '\0';

    return s1;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s1[100];

    puts( eliminate_duplicates( s1, "hello everyone" ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
helo evryon
```

If you want just to output a string without duplicated characters in words and without creating a new string that will be outputted then the functon can loo the following way as shown n the followng demonstraton program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

FILE * eliminate_duplicates( const char *s, FILE *fp )
{
    int is_word = 0;

    for (const char *pos = NULL; *s; ++s)
    {
        if (!isalpha( ( unsigned char ) *s) )
        {
            is_word = 0;
            fputc( *s, fp );
        }
        else
        {
            if (!is_word)
            {
                is_word = 1;
                pos = s;
            }
            if (strchr( pos, *s ) == s)
            {
                fputc( *s, fp );
            }
        }
    }

    return fp;
}

int main( void )
{
    fputc( '\n', eliminate_duplicates("hello everyone", stdout));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Labrynth (Apt name for getting lost in too much code.)

The other very worthwhile comments and answers have already mentioned the shunning of `gets()` and shunning *magic numbers* that are ASCII values of characters, or even using library functions. So, I won't repeat that here.

Beginners often think another copy or a few more variables will eventually lead to a solution, only to get lost in the chaos.

K.I.S.S - Keep It Simple Sunshine! Without chopping up the original string (`strtok()`), or using a 2nd array, or more-and-more variables, there's the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main( void ) {
    char *str = "roll on, mississippi river...\n";
    bool used[ UCHAR_MAX ] = { 0 };

    for( ; *str; str++ )
        if( isalpha( (unsigned char)*str ) ) {
            if( !used[ *str ] )
                putchar( *str );
            used[ *str ]++;
        } else {
            putchar( *str );
            memset( used, 0, sizeof used );
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `rol on, misp rive...`

Since this is a *toy* problem, the possible unnecessary repeated zero-ing of `used[]` is not worth bothering about.

Comment: It's too complicate for me T_T.I'm just a low level programmer and I can"t understand that. sorry...

Comment: If you can point out what you don't understand, I may be able to help you learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- when you call `isduplicate(token[i], res)`: `res` is not a proper string with a null terminator, hence `isduplicate()` has undefined behavior.
- `eliminate()` does not store a null terminator at `res[j]` after copying the non duplicated letters.
- the variable `j` in `eliminate()` is not the same as the one with the same name in `main`.  Defining it as `static` does not make a difference.
- using `gets()` is a security flaw and no longer supported in C23.  Use `fgets()` instead.
- `while (notalphabet(str[i]))` will not stop at the end of the string because the null terminator is not a letter.
- instead of hard coded ASCII values, you should use the macros from `<ctype.h>`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];

    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        char res[100] = { 0 };   // modified string, zero initialized
        size_t j = 0;            // index into res
        size_t tok = 0;          // start of the current word in res
        for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            unsigned char ch = str[i];
            if (isalpha(ch)) {
                // we have a letter: search for it in the current word
                if (strchr(res + tok, ch)) {
                    // duplicate letter: ignore it
                } else {
                    // not a duplicate: append the letter to the current word
                    res[j] = ch;
                    j++;
                }
            } else {
                // separator: copy and set tok to the index of the next character
                res[j] = ch;
                j++;
                tok = j;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The resulting string is: %s", res);
    return 0;
}
```